# How to print RMarkdown code chunk execution times?

Tags: r, profiling, knitr, r-markdown

Just wondering if there's a way to capture (and print) execution time for code chunks in an Rmarkdown document (without wrapping every chunk in `system.time()`).

Ideally I'd like to print an execution time underneath selected code chunks, but I would also be happy with just a summary table showing execution times at the end of the document.

Thx.

Comment: Here are links link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530008/hook-to-time-knitr-chunks , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595280/timing-for-chunks that illustrates the idea using hooks. I have previously found a similar method that accumulates results in a data frame and then prints them in a final step.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for pointing to these earlier answers.